# How to read the contents (source code) of the example.php file without running the php on local server using relative paths?

Tags: php

I have the first .php file called example.php that goes like this:

`<?PHP echo "TEST"; ?>`

I have a second .php file that I would like to use to read the first file that goes like this:

`<? PHP echo file_get_contents('example.php'); ?>`

I gave permissions to the first file for read.

The output I would like to have with the second file is:

"`<?PHP echo "TEST"; ?>`" - as a simple string on the screen without any execution of the code.

Both files are on the same server and in the same directory.

Output that I currently get is white screen, nothing, also no error.
If I write something in the first file out of the PHP like this:

`<?PHP echo "TEST"; ?>123`

Only "123" gets echoed out.

Goal is to read the source of the .php file as a string?

Also this doesn't work as expected:
    `<?PHP 
    $FileName = "example.php";
    $f = fopen($FileName,"r");
    $Res = fread($f, filesize($FileName));
    fclose($f); echo $Res; 
    ?>`

Comment: `<?php
$myfile = fopen("example.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("example.php"));
fclose($myfile);
?>` should do the trick too i think.

Comment: I tried it, it behaves the same as the file_get_contents() - only outputs text next to the php code. I also tried to modify the server limitations, but with no luck. 
The code I tried:
`<?PHP $FileName = "example.php";
 $f = fopen($FileName,"r");
 $Res = fread($f, filesize($FileName));
 fclose($f);
 echo $Res; ?>`

Comment: stratadox posted an answer and cant believe i wasnt thinking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web browser presumably reads `<?PHP echo "TEST"; ?>` and believes it to be an undefined html tag. If I'm correct, you'll see your php tag only when you click "view source".

Try instead:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('example.php'));
```

Comment: Yes, that did it, thank you so much :)

I thought about it too, and then I tried to remove the "<?PHP" as soon as it came with str_replace (), but for some other reason it didn't succeed. 
Again, thank you so much :)